# class file for java.lang.AutoCloseable not found - ActiveMQ code

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm able to successfully execute below code in Eclipse (with JDK 1.6).

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(userName, password, hostName);
// Create a Connection
connection = factory.createConnection();
// start the Connection
connection.start();
//some processes
```

Supporting jars used:

```
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar 
javax.annotation-api-1.2-b01.jar 
javax.jms-api-2.0.jar 
management-api-1.1-rev-1.jar 
activemq-core-5.7.0.jar
```

But getting below compile error when taking build (with JDK 1.6) through ant.

```
[javac] d:\jenkinshome\jobs\DocumentumArtifacts V15 DEV\workspace\javamethods\org\ifc\rms\methods\PermanentDocbaseMethods.java:324: cannot access java.lang.AutoCloseable
[javac] class file for java.lang.AutoCloseable not found
[javac]                    connection.start();
[javac]
```

Any help would be highly beneficial for me!!!

Comment: Interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable` was added in Java 7. The code you are trying to compile is not compatible with Java 6.

Comment: You are really doing active development work on Java 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface [`Autocloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) has been introduced in java 1.7 so it can't be compiled with java 1.6 as reported in javadoc:

> Since: 1.7

Verify if you can use a newer jdk. It depends on the requirements of the project.
If it is not possible you have to use older versions of the libraries that are compatible with java 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.AutoCloseable` does not exist in 1.6

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html:

> **Since:**
>   1.7

Honestly, I am surprised that you have been able to compile and run it in Eclipse. My guess is that Eclipse decides to compile with a newer JDK and you aren't really using 1.6 there.